# Is there a way to parse a template tag inside an extension hook handler?

Tags: tags

As you know, we can't use template tags inside extension hook handlers because those will not be parsed.

However is there an alternate way to access them inside extension hook handlers? Or something like given a tag string, have a function that can parse it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "hook". I thought "hook" was just a trigger point.

Comment: What I mean by 'hook' here is a extension hook handler function. Will update question.

Answer (score 1):

Anything can be parsed in an extension, it just depends on what hook you're using as to what you're going to do with the output.

[template_post_parse](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/template/index.html#template-post-parse) for example passes the templateData, so you can then manipulate it, parse it, do whatever you want with it and then return it.

You'd just use [parse_variables](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/template.html#id6) in the normal way.

Some hooks don't provide tagData directly and therefore there's no way to manipulate it.

**UPDATE**
Yes you can access the template contents and parse them from anywhere (See *disclaimer), but unless the code that implements the hook then continues to processes the template, what you've changed via the hook will be ignored.

e.g.

Original EE code `$myTagData = $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata;`

Hook in EE code

Your Extension code (via the hook) manipulates $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata.

Your code returns to the original EE code flow

Original EE Code continues to use `$myTagData` not your modified `$this->EE->TMPL->tagdata`.

*Disclaimer: Remember that `$this->EE->TMPL->tagdata` is the template code within the tag pair (not the whole template), so if you try to get tagdata independently it probably won't be related to the tagdata that the method with the hook is using (especially a pair loop). And you probably won't be able to use `$this->EE->TMPL->tagdata` to get the tagdata! Some hooks (especially third-party) send the whole parent object, which allows access to different elements that may include the tagdata.

**Importantly the bottom line is, it depends on what hook you're using and what you're trying to do in the Extension.**

Comment: So if templateData is not passed in a certain hook, then I am screwed? There is no way programmatically in hooks to access template contents and parse them?

Comment: You've still not mentioned which hook...? I've updated the answer to explain more.

Comment: I am doing it in a non-native EE hook, `messaging_pm_sent` from a messaging addon. It only provides the message data, the recipients and cc

Comment: So you have the message data and would like to parse it for normal EE tags? That's entirely possible, or do you mean "message data" is the raw variable data that the add-on that contains the hook then uses to parse and insert itself into the email message?

Comment: No. The string I am or want to parse has nothing to do with the message. It's not passed in params nor acccess using $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata. It simply is a hardcoded string that I want to parse.

Comment: Then you'd just use parse_variables with your array of variables to replace and your custom string - you don't have to use tagData.